# How do you ensure that Nuget packages are covered by your configuration management?

Tags: nuget, configuration-management

Our business practices require all configuration information to be stored such that a project can be rebuilt easily without relying on the existence of external resources. That means (among other things) that specific add-ins to Visual Studio that are required to complete the build, whether it is a tool or a class library, must be stored in our configuration management system.

I love Nuget and the power it provides to integrate new features into a project, but it isn't clear to me how we can store Nuget-added libraries into our configuration management system such that future build machines can be correctly set-up to build the project.

- Is this something that has already been considered and I am overlooking it?
- How do you integrate Nuget packages into configuration management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check in your packages folder and below, plus packages.config.